# I can't seem to get my hangman java program working

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a hangman program  and I have no errors but the program will just terminate when I run it. Do you see any issues with my code? Can I add StringBuilder to strings that change in my code?
I also wanted to make create a driver class but not sure what to put in it.

```
package hangman;

import java.util.Random;


public class hangman
{
  public static void main1(String[] args){
  }




  //the word to be guessed

  private String word = null;

  // the array of possible words */
  private String[] wordArray = {"help","word","work","pant", "farm", "blue", "swim", "bike", "jump", "snow"};

  // the random number generator */
  private Random randNumGen = new Random();

  // the characters that were guessed that were wrong */
  private String wrongGuesses = "";

  // the characters that were guessed that were right */
  private char[] rightGuesses = {' ',' ',' ', ' '};



  // Randomly picks the word from the wordArray

  public hangman()
  {
    int index = randNumGen.nextInt(wordArray.length);
    word = wordArray[index];
  }





  public boolean guess()
  {
    boolean done = false;

    Object SimpleInput;
    // get input from user
    String guessStr = ("Enter a letter");

    // check if still have at least one letter
    if (guessStr.length() > 0)
    {
      // get first letter
      char guessChar = guessStr.charAt(0);

      // check this letter
      done = this.guess(guessChar);
    }
    return done;
  }

  //Method to guess a letter 

  public boolean guess(char guessChar)
  {
    int index = word.indexOf(guessChar);
    boolean done = false;

    // if the letter is in the word
    if (index >= 0)
    {


      // add letter to correctly guessed letters 
      rightGuesses[index] = guessChar;


      // check if the user won
      int numRightGuesses = 0;
    if (numRightGuesses == 4)
      {

        done = true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // add letter to string with wrong letters
      wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + guessChar + " ";





      int numWrongGuesses = 0;
    // check if this was the last wrong guess
      if (numWrongGuesses == 6)
      {
        done = true;
      }
    }
    return done;
  }

  /**
   * Method to play the game till the user
   * wins or loses
   */
  public void playGame()
  {
    boolean done = false;
    // loop while we haven't reached the end of the game
    while (!(done = guess()))
    {}
  }




}
```

Comment: First, the main method **needs** to be named main, not main1. Second, it's what gets called when your app is run, so all your startup logic should go in there :)

Comment: u should start by practicing with "hello world" program

Answer (score 1):

You need a startpoint for your program.
The Computer needs to Know where your program begins.

Your `public static void main(String[] args)` method at the beginning has trailing "1" after "main" thats one point. 
The other point is that you must call your game in the main-method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    hangman game = new hangman();
    game.playGame();
}
```

Comment: would there be any other reason why still won't run after I changed my main method to the above?

Answer (score 0):

Your main() method is empty. That is the primary entry point into your app, and it doesn't do anything, so the program exits cleanly. Success…?

Answer (score 0):

replace your main method with the following code, it will create an object of your class and the code inside constructor will be executed

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
      hangman game = new hangman();
      game.PlayGame();
  }
```